# Boolean expression simplification - Short problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I don't know exactly how to simply this problem.
I can clearly see that (A + B) is in all of them but I don't know what to do next.

(A + B + C)(A + B + !C + D)(A + B + !C + !D)

-- Edit 1 --

I am trying to get something like (A + B) + [ (C)(!C + D)(!C + !D) ].
I know this is wrong but this is where I'm trying to get to as the next step.

-- Edit 2 --

The following steps are from Edit one.

(A + B) + [ (C)(!C + D)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (C!C + CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (0 + CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (CD!C) + CD!D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (0) + 0) ]

= (A + B)

-- Edit 3 --

I verified using a Boolean calculator and it seems that the answer is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: You say you don't know what to do *next* but as far as I can see you haven't done anything *first*.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to factoring first, I tried that on paper but I can't seem to get the signs right.
Or are you referring to just distribute everything.

Comment: try additing that, maybe we can spot where you made any mistake.

Comment: You make a good point about $A+B$ being everywhere, and nowhere do you see just $A$ or $B$.  So substitute $E=A+B$ and go on with your simplification.

Comment: I understand what you mean Matthew. I can't seem to understand what to do at this point even if I substitute the E.
When I do so, I don't know how to factor the E from all 3 equations and create a new one. I think thats my main issue here.

Comment: You're getting there. But that should be $(A+B) + [(C)(\ldots)]$, I think. Can you simplify the stuff within the square brackets at all?

Comment: Thanks Matthew and John. I did it.

Comment: You can submit your final solution as an answer (which will close out the question, and give you practice at writing answers). You'll get no credit for being the "chosen answer" when you select this as the correct one, but you'll be giving back to the community that just gave something to you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a handy equivalence:

**Adjacency**

$(P + Q)(P+ !Q)=P$

With that, we can simplify your expression in exactly two steps:

$$(A + B + C)(A + B + !C + D)(A + B + !C + !D)\overset{Adjacency}=$$

$$(A + B + C)(A + B + !C)\overset{Adjacency}=$$

$$A + B$$

Yeah, a good one to put in your boolean algebra toolbox!

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never seen this one before. 
I am currently working on another problem and I am stuck big time on this one.
If u have time, take a quick look at it. Maybe you'll throw another great equivalence there.

Comment: @JohnJohnyPapaJohn All done! :)

Answer (score 2):

(A + B) + [ (C)(!C + D)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (C!C + CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (0 + CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (CD)(!C + !D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (CD!C) + CD!D) ]

= (A + B) + [ (0) + 0) ]

= (A + B)

Comment: That works.  I would have started by distributing the negated C, but whatever works is okay.$${\rm\quad (A + B) + [ (C)(!C + D)(!C + !D) ]\\= (A+B)+[(C)(!C+D!D)]\\=(A+B)+[C!(C+0)]\\=(A+B)+[C!C]\\=(A+B)+0\\=A+B}$$

Comment: You didn't properly distribute the (!C+D)(!C+!D). It should be something like (!C!C)+(!C!D)+(D!C)+(D!D)

Comment: No, it is distributing out the common disjunct: $(x+y)(x+z)=x+yz$

Comment: U got me there thanks